# Como alterar texto de uma tabela html de acordo com o resultado

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Estou fazendo uma tabela em html e queria alterar todos os textos de acordo com um resultado.

Por ex: Se na tabela consta como 1 significa que está em uso, então faz a alteração e substituí o número 1 e põe em uso, e se constar como 0 fica como disponível.

O código ao vivo

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$("td.select:contains('1')").css("background","red");
$("td.select:contains('0')").css("border-bottom","1px solid green");

$("td.select:contains('0')").css("background","green");
$("td.select:contains('0')").css("border-bottom","1px solid green");

});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.25;
}

table {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

table caption {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin: .5em 0 .75em;
}

table tr {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: .35em;
}

table th,
table td {
  padding: .625em;
  text-align: center;
}

table th {
  font-size: .85em;
  letter-spacing: .1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  table {
    border: 0;
  }

  table caption {
    font-size: 1.3em;
  }
  
  table thead {
    border: none;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
  }
  
  table tr {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #ddd;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: .625em;
  }
  
  table td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    display: block;
    font-size: .8em;
    text-align: right;
  }
  
  table td::before {
    /*
    * aria-label has no advantage, it won't be read inside a table
    content: attr(aria-label);
    */
    content: attr(data-label);
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  
  table td:last-child {
    border-bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
   <tbody><tr style="height: 45px; display: table-row;">
    <th width="50">ID</th>
    <th>E-mail</th>
    <th>Senha</th>
    <th>Chave</th>
    <th>Pergunta Secreta</th>
    <th style="width:100px;">Quant. Usuários</th>
    <th width="100">Editar</th>
   </tr>

   
   <tr style="display: table-row;">
    <td>1697</td>
    <td>comprador@hotmail.com</td>
    <td>0798RD7Fdg</td>
    <td>V6BH9-NBJGJ-PP9RM-WJ</td>
    <td>dGBD7der6FV</td>
    <td class="select">0</td>
    <td>
     <div class="btn-group">
      <a class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
       Editar
       <span class="caret"></span>
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
       <li>
        <a href="editar.php?codusuario=1697"><i class="icon-pencil"></i> Editar</a>
        <a class="remover" href="remover.php?codusuario=1697"><i class="icon-trash"></i> Remover</a>
       </li>
      </ul>
     </div>
    </td>
   </tr><tr style="display: table-row;">
    <td>1698</td>
    <td>comprador@outlook.com</td>
    <td>gadygsadysadsa</td>
    <td>Ativada</td>
    <td>lol</td>
    <td class="select">0</td>
    <td>
     <div class="btn-group">
      <a class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
       Editar
       <span class="caret"></span>
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
       <li>
        <a href="editar.php?codusuario=1698"><i class="icon-pencil"></i> Editar</a>
        <a class="remover" href="remover.php?codusuario=1698"><i class="icon-trash"></i> Remover</a>
       </li>
      </ul>
     </div>
    </td>
   </tr><tr style="display: table-row;">
    <td>1699</td>
    <td>comprador@outlook.com</td>
    <td>comprador</td>
    <td>Ativada</td>
    <td>ha9d7293dsas</td>
    <td class="select">0</td>
    <td>
     <div class="btn-group">
      <a class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
       Editar
       <span class="caret"></span>
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
       <li>
        <a href="editar.php?codusuario=1699"><i class="icon-pencil"></i> Editar</a>
        <a class="remover" href="remover.php?codusuario=1699"><i class="icon-trash"></i> Remover</a>
       </li>
      </ul>
     </div>
    </td>
   </tr><tr style="display: table-row;">
    <td>1700</td>
    <td>comprador@hotmail.com</td>
    <td>comprador</td>
    <td>6997438036</td>
    <td>comprador</td>
    <td class="select">0</td>
    <td>
     <div class="btn-group">
      <a class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
       Editar
       <span class="caret"></span>
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
       <li>
        <a href="editar.php?codusuario=1700"><i class="icon-pencil"></i> Editar</a>
        <a class="remover" href="remover.php?codusuario=1700"><i class="icon-trash"></i> Remover</a>
       </li>
      </ul>
     </div>
    </td>
   </tr><tr style="display: table-row;">
    <td>1701</td>
    <td>comprador@outlook.com</td>
    <td>comprador</td>
    <td>7311697876</td>
    <td>07U90J0DJ0msds</td>
    <td class="select">0</td>
    <td>
     <div class="btn-group">
      <a class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
       Editar
       <span class="caret"></span>
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
       <li>
        <a href="editar.php?codusuario=1701"><i class="icon-pencil"></i> Editar</a>
        <a class="remover" href="remover.php?codusuario=1701"><i class="icon-trash"></i> Remover</a>
       </li>
      </ul>
     </div>
    </td>
   </tr><tr style="display: table-row;">
    <td>1702</td>
    <td>comprador@hotmail.com</td>
    <td>9u2j907syua0d823</td>
    <td>B6J9-G4Q7-R7R7</td>
    <td>203uj0dsa8023</td>
    <td class="select">0</td>
    <td>
     <div class="btn-group">
      <a class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
       Editar
       <span class="caret"></span>
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
       <li>
        <a href="editar.php?codusuario=1702"><i class="icon-pencil"></i> Editar</a>
        <a class="remover" href="remover.php?codusuario=1702"><i class="icon-trash"></i> Remover</a>
       </li>
      </ul>
     </div>
    </td>
   </tr><tr style="display: table-row;">
    <td>1703</td>
    <td>comprador@hotmail.com</td>
    <td>0u2j08dsad0923</td>
    <td>B9B9-J3B9-M7C8</td>
    <td>923hda7sd923</td>
    <td class="select">0</td>
    <td>
     <div class="btn-group">
      <a class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
       Editar
       <span class="caret"></span>
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
       <li>
        <a href="editar.php?codusuario=1703"><i class="icon-pencil"></i> Editar</a>
        <a class="remover" href="remover.php?codusuario=1703"><i class="icon-trash"></i> Remover</a>
       </li>
      </ul>
     </div>
    </td>
   </tr><tr style="display: table-row;">
    <td>1696</td>
    <td>comprador@hotmail.com</td>
    <td>i9kI8SUhnd7gtBS</td>
    <td>N64RC-4F927-6YY6K-T9</td>
    <td>0U99hy9dysdh9sn</td>
    <td class="select">1</td>
    <td>
     <div class="btn-group">
      <a class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
       Editar
       <span class="caret"></span>
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
       <li>
        <a href="editar.php?codusuario=1696"><i class="icon-pencil"></i> Editar</a>
        <a class="remover" href="remover.php?codusuario=1696"><i class="icon-trash"></i> Remover</a>
       </li>
      </ul>
     </div>
    </td>
   </tr>  </tbody></table>
```

Comment: Use Ajax para isso. Tem muito material aqui no site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar o `.html()` no mesmo seletor:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("td.select:contains('1')").css("background", "red");
  $("td.select:contains('0')").css("border-bottom", "1px solid green");

  $("td.select:contains('0')").css("background", "green");
  $("td.select:contains('0')").css("border-bottom", "1px solid green");

  $("td.select:contains('1')").html('Ativa');
  $("td.select:contains('0')").html('Inativa');
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.25;
}

table {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

table caption {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin: .5em 0 .75em;
}

table tr {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: .35em;
}

table th,
table td {
  padding: .625em;
  text-align: center;
}

table th {
  font-size: .85em;
  letter-spacing: .1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  table {
    border: 0;
  }
  table caption {
    font-size: 1.3em;
  }
  table thead {
    border: none;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
  }
  table tr {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #ddd;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: .625em;
  }
  table td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    display: block;
    font-size: .8em;
    text-align: right;
  }
  table td::before {
    /*
    * aria-label has no advantage, it won't be read inside a table
    content: attr(aria-label);
    */
    content: attr(data-label);
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  table td:last-child {
    border-bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr style="height: 45px; display: table-row;">
      <th width="50">ID</th>
      <th>E-mail</th>
      <th>Senha</th>
      <th>Chave</th>
      <th>Pergunta Secreta</th>
      <th style="width:100px;">Quant. Usuários</th>
      <th width="100">Editar</th>
    </tr>
    <tr style="display: table-row;">
      <td>1697</td>
      <td>comprador@hotmail.com</td>
      <td>0798RD7Fdg</td>
      <td>V6BH9-NBJGJ-PP9RM-WJ</td>
      <td>dGBD7der6FV</td>
      <td class="select">0</td>
      <td>
        <div class="btn-group">
          <a class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
       Editar
       <span class="caret"></span>
      </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>
              <a href="editar.php?codusuario=1697"><i class="icon-pencil"></i> Editar</a>
              <a class="remover" href="remover.php?codusuario=1697"><i class="icon-trash"></i> Remover</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="display: table-row;">
      <td>1698</td>
      <td>comprador@outlook.com</td>
      <td>gadygsadysadsa</td>
      <td>Ativada</td>
      <td>lol</td>
      <td class="select">0</td>
      <td>
        <div class="btn-group">
          <a class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
       Editar
       <span class="caret"></span>
      </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>
              <a href="editar.php?codusuario=1698"><i class="icon-pencil"></i> Editar</a>
              <a class="remover" href="remover.php?codusuario=1698"><i class="icon-trash"></i> Remover</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="display: table-row;">
      <td>1699</td>
      <td>comprador@outlook.com</td>
      <td>comprador</td>
      <td>Ativada</td>
      <td>ha9d7293dsas</td>
      <td class="select">0</td>
      <td>
        <div class="btn-group">
          <a class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
       Editar
       <span class="caret"></span>
      </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>
              <a href="editar.php?codusuario=1699"><i class="icon-pencil"></i> Editar</a>
              <a class="remover" href="remover.php?codusuario=1699"><i class="icon-trash"></i> Remover</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="display: table-row;">
      <td>1700</td>
      <td>comprador@hotmail.com</td>
      <td>comprador</td>
      <td>6997438036</td>
      <td>comprador</td>
      <td class="select">0</td>
      <td>
        <div class="btn-group">
          <a class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
       Editar
       <span class="caret"></span>
      </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>
              <a href="editar.php?codusuario=1700"><i class="icon-pencil"></i> Editar</a>
              <a class="remover" href="remover.php?codusuario=1700"><i class="icon-trash"></i> Remover</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="display: table-row;">
      <td>1701</td>
      <td>comprador@outlook.com</td>
      <td>comprador</td>
      <td>7311697876</td>
      <td>07U90J0DJ0msds</td>
      <td class="select">0</td>
      <td>
        <div class="btn-group">
          <a class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
       Editar
       <span class="caret"></span>
      </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>
              <a href="editar.php?codusuario=1701"><i class="icon-pencil"></i> Editar</a>
              <a class="remover" href="remover.php?codusuario=1701"><i class="icon-trash"></i> Remover</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="display: table-row;">
      <td>1702</td>
      <td>comprador@hotmail.com</td>
      <td>9u2j907syua0d823</td>
      <td>B6J9-G4Q7-R7R7</td>
      <td>203uj0dsa8023</td>
      <td class="select">0</td>
      <td>
        <div class="btn-group">
          <a class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
       Editar
       <span class="caret"></span>
      </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>
              <a href="editar.php?codusuario=1702"><i class="icon-pencil"></i> Editar</a>
              <a class="remover" href="remover.php?codusuario=1702"><i class="icon-trash"></i> Remover</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="display: table-row;">
      <td>1703</td>
      <td>comprador@hotmail.com</td>
      <td>0u2j08dsad0923</td>
      <td>B9B9-J3B9-M7C8</td>
      <td>923hda7sd923</td>
      <td class="select">0</td>
      <td>
        <div class="btn-group">
          <a class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
       Editar
       <span class="caret"></span>
      </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>
              <a href="editar.php?codusuario=1703"><i class="icon-pencil"></i> Editar</a>
              <a class="remover" href="remover.php?codusuario=1703"><i class="icon-trash"></i> Remover</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="display: table-row;">
      <td>1696</td>
      <td>comprador@hotmail.com</td>
      <td>i9kI8SUhnd7gtBS</td>
      <td>N64RC-4F927-6YY6K-T9</td>
      <td>0U99hy9dysdh9sn</td>
      <td class="select">1</td>
      <td>
        <div class="btn-group">
          <a class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
       Editar
       <span class="caret"></span>
      </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>
              <a href="editar.php?codusuario=1696"><i class="icon-pencil"></i> Editar</a>
              <a class="remover" href="remover.php?codusuario=1696"><i class="icon-trash"></i> Remover</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Obrigado Guilherme! Isso resolveu o meu problema.